# How to make different classes conform to the same protocol with different functionality?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift-protocols

I apologize beforehand if title is unclear, but I like to know how this is possible with some code snippets first:

ClassOne:

```
@objc protocol FetchProtocol
{
    var someVar: Bool
    {
        get set
    }

    var someUIView: FetchProtocol
    {
        get set
    }

    func someFuncOne()
}

class ClassOne: UIViewController, FetchProtocol
{
    ...

    @IBOutlet var someUIView: FetchProtocol!

    ....

}
```

ClassTwo:

```
@objc protocol FetchProtocol
{
    var someVar: Bool
    {
        get set
    }

    var someTableView: FetchProtocol
    {
        get set
    }

    var someUIView: FetchProtocol
    {
        get set
    }

    func someFuncOne()
    func someFuncTwo()
}

class ClassTwo: UIViewController, FetchProtocol
{
    ...

    @IBOutlet var someTableView: FetchProtocol!
    @IBOutlet var someUIView: FetchProtocol!

    ....

}
```

Both `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo` conform to the same `FetchProtocol` and both classes use the same `someVar` as well as `someFuncOne`, but `ClassTwo` also uses `someTableView` and `someFuncTwo` unique to only `ClassTwo`.

How can I use the same protocol between both classes, but the other class has "additional" different skeletal implementation?

For example, something like the following:

```
if let vc = currentVC as? FetchProtocol
{
    if vc.someVar == true
    {
        // Check if vc is of class type ClassOne, call someFuncOne

        // Otherwise if vc is of class type ClassTwo, call someFuncOne and someFuncTwo

    }
}
```

Is something like the above possible using protocols and if so, how to properly implement it, or is there another alternative?

Comment: Make protocol 2 inherit from protocol 1, extends protocol 2 to contain whatever extra stuff you want.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: makes sense, but how do I check if `vc` is of a certain class type before calling the additional `someFuncTwo`?

Comment: Why would you be checking which class it is? That defeats the purpose of having protocols in the first place

Comment: The whole point of a protocol is to decouple the declaration of functions from their implementation. If you're checking your `vc` against specific classes, you completely forgo this decoupling, because now only those specific classes you checked against will be usable

Comment: You should be checking against the protocol type, such that any class or struct conforming to your protocol is valid

Comment: Imagine this: you've got a cold and you want some medical advice. You know doctors who's passed their exams are eligible to provide medical advice. There exists protocol that states that anyone who conforms (by passing their exams) can provide medical advice. By your reasoning: You know a doctor named Mr. Smith. But the only doctor in town is Mrs. Johnson. You check to see if she's Mr. Smith, and she's not. So you conclude that she can't provide you medical advice.

Comment: Clearly this isn't right. You should be checking if the individual conforms to the protocol "MedicalAdviceProvider", so that you can go to eligible doctor, regardless of the who the concrete individual is.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't compile and I think you're overcomplicating things and *use protocols for the sake of using them.*. There is no need to use any protocols at all if all you want to do is this:

```
if let vc = currentVC as? FetchProtocol
{
    if vc.someVar == true
    {
        // Check if vc is of class type ClassOne, call someFuncOne

        // Otherwise if vc is of class type ClassTwo, call someFuncOne and someFuncTwo

    }
}
```

Why not delete all protocols and just do:

```
if currentVC.someVar {
    if let class1 = currentVC as? ClassOne {
        class1.someFuncOne()
    } else if let class2 = currentVC as? ClassTwo {
        class2.someFuncOne()
        class2.someFuncTwo()
    }
}
```

You don't really need protocols here because whether protocols exist or not, you still have to check whether `currentVC` is `ClassOne` or `ClassTwo`.

Protocols act like "black boxes". Consider this method:

```
func foo(fetchObj: FetchProtocol) {
    fetchObj.someFuncOne()
}
```

`foo` doesn't care about what `fetchObj` *really is*. It just says "I don't care what you are, just do `someFuncOne`!"

What you're trying to do here is completely the opposite: "I *do* care what you are. If you're `ClassOne`, do this. If you're `ClassTwo`, do that."

Comment: your `You don't really need protocols` is right . I guess I was trying to avoid repetitive code because `someVar` is declared and used in both classes, so if I implement what you suggested, then I would need to do `if class1.someVar == true { class1.someFuncOne() }` as well as `if class2.someVar == true { class2.someFuncOne() class2.someFuncTwo()  }`, which gets repetitive if I have multiple classes using `someVar` in its own unique way

Comment: @Pangu Then only make a protocol that has `someVar`: `protocol FetchProtocol { var someVar: Bool { get set } }`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is quite abstract, and pretty hard to follow, but this does what you're asking for. That being said, I suspect there's no need for you to be using protocols here at all.

```
protocol P1 {
    var someVar1: String { get }

    func func1();
}

protocol P2: P1 {
    var someVar2: String { get }
    func func2();
}


class C1: P1 {
    var someVar1 = "String 1 in C1"

    func func1() {
        print(someVar1)
    }
}

class C2: P2 {
    var someVar1 = "String 1 in C2"
    var someVar2 = "String 2 in C2"

    func func1() {
        print(someVar1)
    }

    func func2() {
        print(someVar2)
    }
}


func foo(with object: P1) {
    object.func1()

    if let object = object as? P2 {
        object.func2()
    }
}

print("Test case 1:")
foo(with: C1())
print("Test case 1:\n")
foo(with: C2())
```